# Block users from editing own cell after data input

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to block users from editing their own input. Right now, when the owner inputs data on the column, it is blocked for other users, but when other users input their data, it adds the note after a few seconds but doesn't lock the cell for them.

```
`function onEdit(e) { 
  var active =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getCurrentCell();

  if(active.getColumn() == 5){
    active.protect().removeEditor("user email")
    active.setNote("Locked")};
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation for the [removeEditor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#removeeditoruser) method, the current user can't be removed from a protection. You're able to remove all the others editors from the cell (excluding the sheet's owner and current user) with [removeUsers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#removeeditorsemailaddresses) method. In case the sheet also has domain edit permission, you can remove it by using [setDomainEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#setdomainediteditable) method.

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var active =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getCurrentCell();  
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();

  if(active.getColumn() == 5){
    var protection = active.protect();

    // This part is only needed if the cell/sheet has domain edit permission
    protection.addEditor(me);
    if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
      protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }

    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    active.setNote("Locked")
  };
}
```